# How to calculate sensitivity and specificity given AUC score?

Tags: roc-auc, sensitivity

I couldn't find any relevant information on how to calculate sensitivity and specificity with AUC score. There is one picture that presents what I want, however I wasn't able to interpret it for my numbers.
[image]

My AUC results are different and would like to calculate sensitivity and specificity (as shown in the above picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specificity and sensitivity reported in that table are simply the x and y coordinates of the red dots in the ROC graphs.

And the red dots are instead the points with maximum [Youden's index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youden%27s_J_statistic), defined as:

$J = sensitivity + specificity - 1$

So basically J= y-x for each point of the ROC curve. Equivalently, since y=x is the identity line (or chance line when talking about ROC curves), you can define "point with maximum Youden's index" as the point with max height above the identity line.

So to get your specificity and sensitivity as in that table, simply compute the Youden's index for each point, then choose the point with max J and its x and y values will be your specificity and sensitivity.